# How to install bigbluebutton on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: bigbluebutton

```
I have followed this http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/081InstallationUbuntu#Installing_BigBlueButton_0.81 link to install bigbluebutton. But when I give sudo apt-get install bigbluebutton I have encounter this error.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bigbluebutton : Depends: bbb-config but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: red5 but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: bbb-common but it is not going to be installed
 ruby1.9.2 : Depends: libffi5 but it is not installable
             Depends: libyaml-0-2 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

I cant solve this error. Can please anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for Ubuntu 13.04 for BigBlueButton.  I am the developer of the Ubuntu packages, and I can share with you that as part of the next release (after 0.81), we'll be upgrading the packaging for Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Comment: The latest release of BigBlueButton supports installation on Ubuntu 14.04, see http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html.